# Объединение двух функций DataTables javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

у меня есть два скрипта для datatables, мне нужно их объединить, чтобы работали оба (каждый по отдельности работает ), я не понимаю, как это сделать.

[Скрипт поиска по каждому столбцу](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }
    });

} );
```

[Скрипт добавления кнопок](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

У меня не получается объединить их, либо один работает, либо другой, либо выскакивает ошибка, как правильно их объединить?

Comment: "либо выскакивает ошибка" - ??

Comment: @Igor ну там ошибка рода, нельзя переинициализировать DataTable или что-то вроде этого, но я пытался просто методом тыка, ибо не знаю, как правильно и не могу найти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
            $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />');
            });
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;
                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that.search( this.value ).draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что автору нужно, чтобы скрипты оставались отдельными. Посмотрим.